# How to observe previous and current value in RxSwift for UITableView tap/selection?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have the following code in my `UIViewController`:

```
  _ = viewModel.selectedCountryId.asObservable()
       .distinctUntilChanged()
        .scan((0, 0), accumulator: { (prev, curr) in
            return zip(prev, curr)
        })
        .subscribe(onNext: {
            let prevCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: previous, section: 0))
            prevCell?.accessoryType = .none
            let currCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: curr, section: 0))
            currCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)`
```

I don't know what to do on `scan` which I believe to be the solution by looking into some SO posts.

What I want to achieve is selecting a row and deselecting the previous one so as to make the tableview have the single selection mechanism with the checkmark icon on the right.

I use a `Variable<Int>` from the viewModel because I need to save which row I selected to pass it to another view controller after making some operations.

If anything is incorrect, please give some recommendation. I am still a beginner in MVVM e RxSwift.

**EDIT**:

Here is the subscription when an item is selected:

`_ = tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath in
            self?.viewModel.selectedCountryId.value = indexPath.row
        })`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer zip for this use-case than scan.

```
Observable.zip(viewModel.selectedCountryId.asObservable(), viewModel.selectedCountryId.asObservable().skip(1)) {
  ($0, $1)
}.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (previous, curr) in
  let prevCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: previous, section: 0))
  prevCell?.accessoryType = .none
  let currCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: curr, section: 0))
  currCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Zip will emit for each combination of the observables. As on the second one we skip a value, we'll get previous and current.
You might want to add a startWith operator before your subscribe to add the checkmark on the initially selected cell.

Bind your selection:

```
tableView.rx.itemSelected.map { $0.row }.bind(to: self.viewModel.selectedCountryId).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```